# Cannot attach CSV to Outlook email from Rstudio? Error:[Cannot locate 0 name(s) attachments in COM object (status = -2147023174)]

Tags: r, email, automation, outlook

I am currently attempting to send a CSV from Rstudio to my audience. Here is the code I am using to send out an Outlook email

```
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] =  "Audience"
Email[["attachments"]]$Add("C:\\Users\\santi\\Documents\\Cost Changes CSV\\0021.csv")
outMail[["subject"]] = "RStudio Test"
outMail[["body"]] = "Sending this From Rstudio" 
outMail$Send()
```

Everything works other than the attachment. I get the following error:

```
Error in Email[["attachments"]] : 
  Cannot locate 0 name(s) attachments in COM object (status = -2147023174)
```

**I have tried the following in case my slashes are incorrect:**

```
Email[["attachments"]]$Add("C:\\Users\\santi\\Documents\\Cost Changes CSV\\0021.csv")
Email[["attachments"]]$Add("C:/Users/santi/Documents/Cost Changes CSV/0021.csv")
Email[["attachments"]]$Add("C:\Users\santi\Documents\Cost Changes CSV\0021.csv")
Email[["attachments"]]$Add("C://Users//santi//Documents//Cost Changes CSV//0021.csv")
```

Each attempt has an error, I read that the double back slash is best practice but that is where I am having issues.

Answer (score 0):

`-2147023174` is `RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE`, which means Outlook was closed while your code was running.

Comment: OutlookSpy - click "Error Code Lookup"